"Objcopy: error: the input file '*.dll' is empty" when running the edk2 build script in linux
I've been trying to build the edk2 from source in a Kali 2023.3 VM, followed every step from the linux guide, but I got a few error messages just like the one in the title for some files like "MnpDxe.dll" each time I run the "build" command.
"Make -C BaseTools" works just fine btw, the GCC version is 13.1, python 3.11 and the config is "TARGET_ARCH=X64, TOOL_CHAIN_TAG=GCC5, ACTIVE_PLATFORM=MdeModulePkg/MdeModulePkg.dsc". Also tried the "EmulatorPkg" platform, no luck (I'm specifically after the emulator to use alongside QEMU).
Any ideas?
